# Does the "Only" part of the "Due Date Only" label of Task.ActivityDate have some significance?

Tags: tasks, standard-objects, describesobject, describefieldresult

This describe call:

```
Task.ActivityDate.getDescribe().getLabel()
```

returns "Due Date Only" rather than "Due Date" (that is used in e.g. the Task edit page).

Is there some significance to the "Only" part of the label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems likely we can attribute it to the linkage of `Event` and `Task` as `Activities`, and the fact that `Event` has a field called `ActivityDateTime` in addition to `ActivityDate`.

```
system.debug(Task.ActivityDate.getDescribe().getLabel()); // Due Date Only
system.debug(Event.ActivityDate.getDescribe().getLabel()); // Due Date Only
system.debug(Event.ActivityDateTime.getDescribe().getLabel()); //Due Date Time
```

Even though `Task` does not have an `ActvityDateTime` field, they probably wanted to maintain consistency across the two objects.

Comment: Thanks - makes sense. I have some describe-based logic and I'm trying to decide whether to drop the "Only" part as it looks pretty weird in my UI.

Comment: For a package? In your own org you could just change the label. I agree it's unsightly, and the code to swap out the label is probably going to be unsightly as well. :(

Comment: Yeah packaged code. I've added `String fieldLabel = f == Task.ActivityDate && dfr.getLabel() == 'Due Date Only' ? 'Due Date' : dfr.getLabel();`.